# Spring boot @ExceptionHandler not catching subclass exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have made some subclass for exception handling. The method throws a subclass exception. I have made @ExceptionHandler for both super class as well as subclasses. But only if there is no handling for super class of exception (handleSuperException(SuperclassExceptionexception e)), then the subclass exceptions are handled. SubClassAException, SubClassBException, SubClassCException extends SuperclassExceptionexception.

```
 public class Controller @PostMapping("/path/") {
       public ResponseEntity<String> method() throws   SuperclassException{
 }
    @ExceptionHandler(SuperclassException.class)   
public ResponseEntity handleSuperException(SuperclassExceptionexception e) {
       //hadle superclass related
    }

 @ExceptionHandler({SubClassAException.class, SubClassBException.class, SubClassCException.class}) 
public ResponseEntity handleSubClassException(SuperclassExceptionexception e) {
//handle more specific
}
```

But it never goes to handleSubClassException even if subclass exceptions are thrown.

Comment: I believe this is like `catch` clauses, you have to specify the subclasses before the super class. Flip the two methods. [This Spring article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#controller-based-exception-handling) shows it that way too, though it doesn't explicitly say anything about order.

Comment: I did the flip one too. doesnt help

Comment: I wonder if it's because the signature for the subclass handler is the same as that for the parent class.  Try creating an individual handler for any subclass exception and see if that gets called.

Comment: I just looked at the Spring Boot 2.2.0 / Spring 5.2.0 source code, and the parameter type is only used if no exception is listed in the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation. The actual exception is then matched to the listed exceptions and the listed exception with the smallest *depth* from the actual exception is chosen, i.e. the more specific subclass exception should always be chosen, regardless of method order.

Comment: It is strange also tried with instanceof in the superclassexception handler method. Somehow it is not going inside the if clause

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that `SubClassAException` actually **`extends`** `SuperclassException`?

Comment: I am facing same kinda problem. :(

Answer (score 4):

*Unable to reproduce!*

Here is [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), tested with Spring Boot 2.2.0 (Spring 5.2.0).

```
package web.controller;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class FailController {

    @GetMapping("/dmz/fail")
    public String failSuper() {
        throw new SuperclassException("failSuper()");
    }

    @GetMapping("/dmz/failA")
    public String failA() {
        throw new SubClassAException("failA()");
    }

    @GetMapping("/dmz/failB")
    public String failB() {
        throw new SubClassBException("failB()");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(SuperclassException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleSuperException(SuperclassException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("handleSuperException: " + e);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({SubClassAException.class, SubClassBException.class}) 
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleSubClassException(SuperclassException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("handleSubClassException: " + e);
    }

}

class SuperclassException extends RuntimeException {
    public SuperclassException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class SubClassAException extends SuperclassException {
    public SubClassAException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class SubClassBException extends SuperclassException {
    public SubClassBException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

<sup>*I'm using `/dmz/` so the Spring Security setup won't require login. In a plain vanilla Spring Boot setup, that will of course not be needed.*</sup>

*Output (`http://localhost:8080/dmz/fail`)*

```
handleSuperException: web.controller.SuperclassException: failSuper()
```

*Output (`http://localhost:8080/dmz/failA`)*

```
handleSubClassException: web.controller.SubClassAException: failA()
```

*Output (`http://localhost:8080/dmz/failB`)*

```
handleSubClassException: web.controller.SubClassBException: failB()
```